# Find the number of distinct real roots of $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **Problem**:Find the number of distinct real roots of $(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3=0$ where $a,b,c$ are distinct real numbers
>
> **Solution**:$(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3=0$
>
> $3x^3-3x^2(a+b+c)+3x(a^2+b^2+c^2)-a^3-b^3-c^3=0$
>
> By Descartes rule of sign,number of positive real roots $=3$

But are they distinct $?$

Answer :- number of distinct real roots $ =1$

Comment: Descartes' rule of signs doesn't tell you that - it tells you whether the number of positive roots is even or odd. Also, $a+b+c$ and $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ could be negative or positive depending on $a,b,c$

Comment: Descartes Rule of signs does not answer the question, for (i) it gives an upper bound on the number of positive roots, not the number and (ii) we cannot count sign changes by looking at $+$ and $-$ signs, some coefficients may not have the sign they appear to have. Also, the answer is not $3$.

Comment: This isn't really a Number Theory question. Do you know about Rolle's Theorem from Calculus?

Comment: I know Rolle's Theorem.But don't know "how to solve this question with it"

Comment: @Cocopuffs @ André Nicolas, I got your points.But how can we solve this question

Comment: What does Rolle's Theorem imply about what happens to the derivative of a (differentiable) function between two real zeros of the function?

Comment: the derivative of a (differentiable) function between two real zeros of the function vanishes

Comment: Your use of Descartes' Rule may be wrong: if $\;a,b,c<0\;$ , then the cubic has no change of signs...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $$f(x)=(x-a)^3+(x-b)^3+(x-c)^3$$ then $$f'(x)=3(x-a)^2+3(x-b)^2+3(x-c)^2$$ Since $a,b,c$ are distinct real numbers $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and therefore $f$ is strictly increasing and therefore it has only one real root.

EDIT: The last statement is true since $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $3$ ($a_0>0$) so $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = -\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: This means,every strictly increasing function has only one real root

Comment: @ kedrigern, you might want to include that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$.

Comment: Since $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $3$, I assumed the rest was clear.

Comment: Every strictly increasing function has at most one real root. In this case it is exactly one since (as J A S O N pointed out) $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Set $m=(a+b+c)/3$, $A=a-m$, $B=b-m$, $C=c-m$ and $x=y+m$. Then your equation becomes
$$
(y-A)^3 + (y-B)^3 + (y-C)^3 = 0
$$
and, since $A+B+C=0$, your expansion applies to give
$$
y^3+(A^2+B^2+C^2)-\frac{A^3+B^3+C^3}{3}=0
$$
which is a suppressed cubic, whose discriminant is
$$
\frac{1}{4}\biggl(-\frac{A^3+B^3+C^3}{3}\biggr)^2+\frac{1}{27}(A^2+B^2+C^2)^3>0
$$
so the equation has only one real root.

Answer (score 0):

Let's substitute the variable: $x=y+\frac{(a+b+c)}{3}$

The equation will now look like

$$3y^3+(2a^2-2ab-2ac+2b^2-2bc+2c^2)y+\frac{(a+b-2c)(a-3b+c)(b-2a+c)}{9}=0$$

Now we apply Cardano's method.

$$Q=\left(\frac{2a^2-2ab-2ac+2b^2-2bc+2c^2}{3}\right)^3+\left(\frac{\frac{(a+b-2c)(a-3b+c)(b-2a+c)}{9}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{8}{27}(a^2-ab-ac+b^2-bc+c^2)^3+\frac{1}{324}(a+b-2c)^2(a-2b+c)^2(b-2a+c)^2$$

Then the answer is given depending on the sign of Q.

If $Q>0$ there is only one real root

If $Q<0$ there are three distinct real roots

If $Q=0$ there are two distinct real roots.